# Arrhenius equation derivation

Tags: kinetics

I couldn't find the derivation of Arrhenius equation. So, How can we derive the Arrhenius equation: 
$k = A \mathrm e^{-E_\mathrm a/(R T)}$?

Comment: Well, the Wikipedia article gives the original Arrhenius references if you would like to follow his thinking. But, what do you mean by 'derivation'? This isn't something that comes out of a pure math proof starting from F=ma. And, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, depending on the system.

Comment: As already pointed it out, the Arrhenius equation isn't born out of pure math. Thinking of it more like an empirical equation that fits experimental data in most situations (and sometimes it doesn't). "Arrhenius-like equations" do come out of theoretical considerations when you look at collision theory or transition state theory.

Answer (score 3):

The equation is rooted in experimental observations. It is not derivable from any physical formalism, and it is not the best way to describe many reactions. Similar equations can be derived from Transition State Theory. It is important to note that the similarities are limited to the functional form.